# Object slicing or UB risk?

Tags: c++, inheritance, undefined-behavior

There's a couple of base classes outside my control like this:-

```
class BaseNode // Just a POD class. No VTable
{
  void foo();
}

class BaseHost 
{
public:
  BaseNode *getNode()
  {
    ...
  } 
}
```

I want to "extend" the functionality of `BaseNode::foo`, but the class is effectively sealed.

Here's the suggestion:-

```
class MyNode: public BaseNode 
{
  void foo()
  {
    // do my stuff..., then
    BaseNode::foo();
  }    
}

class MyHost: public BaseHost 
{
public:
  MyNode *getNode()
  {
    return (MyNode*) BaseHost::getNode(); // Slicing or UB risk?
  }   
}
```

Things will go badly wrong if `MyNode` introduces additional class members, or virtual methods - but if those constraints are met, do I still have UB?

Any other gotchas, or do I rethink the design entirely.?

Comment: If anyone does something like `BaseHost *host = new MyHost; host->getNode()->foo()`, you realise that your `foo` method won't get called, right?  That's not UB, but doesn't sound very useful.

Comment: Oh, wait, casting something that isn't a `MyNode*` to a `MyNode*` (and then presumably dereferencing it at some point) is **definitely** UB.

Comment: My advice: Never inherit from a logically sealed class. (Use composition)

Comment: @DieterLücking  - Understood. An issue is that I have a fair amount of client code in existence using BaseNode*/BaseHost, and I'm looking for the easiest way of updating it. Extending by Composition, where the base class is always returned as a pointer (`getNode()`) gives me a lots of object lifetime management pain.

Comment: @Roddy extending by inheritance doesn't fix any of that pain

Comment: @M.M Understood. I was thinking that my 'composed' class would have the same "return as raw pointer" interface as the derived, which would add significant pain. But I've bitten the bullet and changed the 'composed' interface (and any client code) to use return by value, which buries the pain elsewhere :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a downcasting shall be used with extreme care: it can very easily lead to UB.

The standard guarantees that you can safely convert from `MyNode*` to `BaseNode*`:

> **4.10/3:** A prvalue of type “pointer to cv D”, where D is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv B”, where B
>   is a base class of D. If B is an inaccessible or ambiguous base class
>   of D, a program that necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. The
>   result of the conversion is a pointer to the base class subobject of
>   the derived class object. The null pointer value is converted to the
>   null pointer value of the destination type.

But let's play with the fire: the standard also let you can cast from  `BaseNode*` to `MyNode*` under certain conditions :

> **5.2.9/11:** A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D,” where
>   D is a class derived  from B, if a valid standard conversion from
>   “pointer to D” to “pointer to B” exists, cv2 is the same
>   cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, cv1, and B is
>   **neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D**. The null pointer value  is converted to the null pointer
>   value of the destination type. **If the prvalue of type “pointer to
>   cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a subobject of an object of type
>   D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D.
>   *Otherwise, the behavior is undefined***

I try to translating these quotes into plain text:

- If you are sure that `BaseHost::getNode()` returns an upcasted pointer to a `MyNode` object, and you have no virtual inheritance in your class hierarchy, then it's ok.
- But if `BaseHost::getNode()` would return something else (e.g. a pointer to a plain `BaseNode` or to another sibling derivate of `BaseNode`) you'll have UB.

As said, it's dangerous: the UB might already happen during the pointer conversion, before you even attempt to dereference the pointer.  So better try to avoid it.  If you'd have a polymorphic `BaseNode` class (e.g. with a virtual destructor), you could use a safer [`dynamic_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).